# How can I make Optifine compatible with FTB?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-optifine

I want Optifine compatibility with the Direwolf20 pack because it can in theory increase my Frames Per Second (FPS). I am willing to accept no for an answer.

Comment: The FTB launcher allows you to point to external .zip file extensions to load when selecting your mod pack. What have you tried?

Comment: @DanRasmussen It seems to conflict with Twilight Forest though

Comment: What's the conflict? I'm using both right now, though I haven't visited the Twilight Forest yet.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That was probably a client-side problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FTB launcher allows you to point to external .zip file extensions to load when selecting your mod pack. You can select the Optifine .zip to be included as a "jar mod" when the modpack's own mods are loaded, and it saves you from editing the .jar yourself.

I've done this before, and it *does* install Optifine, and if changing visual settings, zoom, etc. is your goal it works just fine. Though personally I found my FPS to drop; I'm not sure why and uninstalled it before I did too much investigation.

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to have any effect (in that the menus in the options menu don't change).

Comment: No, it's a jar mod. ("Core mods" are another kind of forge mod.)

Comment: Aside, re: fps dropping: which edition did you install? Standard, Ultra, or Lite? Ultra and Standard not only increase fps, but also add features that will drop fps, sometimes for a net loss if the machine isn't fast enough.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I believe I installed Ultra. My machine's pretty good, and can handle it in vanilla, but my FPS is good enough without it so I didn't dig too far into the problem. I may again, just to see.

Comment: This no longer works in 1.6.x packs as Optifine changed the install method to a self-installer (so you no longer have access to the jar file). Just a heads up to anyone looking.